# How to check if git has differences between 2 branch in a bash script

Tags: bash, git

I need to check in a bash script if there is differences between 2 branch in a git repository. I know it is possible to see differences with git diff. However i need to use it in **if**.

how can i do that?

For example:

```
git diff ......
if [ $? -eq 1 ] 
then
    echo "will do something in here"
fi
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(edit: swapped --exit-code for --quiet which suppresses output)

`git diff --quiet` will cause the command to set an exit code similar to the normal diff command if there are differences.

```
if ! git diff --quiet <commit1> <commit2> ; then
  echo "Different"
else
  echo "Not different"
fi
```

If you care about inspecting the specific error code:

```
git diff --quiet <commit1> <commit2>
case $? in
  0) echo "Not different" ;;
  1) echo "Different" ;;
  128) echo "Invalid commit id(s)" ;;
  *) echo "Unknown error" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks, good however it will be perfect if it will compare it with 1 and 0. Because for example; if it cant found the branch, command returns 128 which will echo "Not different"

Comment: * *which will echo "Different"*

Comment: Sure, I can add an example for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the branch names
BRANCH1="master"
BRANCH2="my-feature-branch"

# Check if there are differences between the two branches
DIFFERENCES=$(git diff --name-only $BRANCH1 $BRANCH2)

# If there are differences, print a message
if [ -n "$DIFFERENCES" ]; then
  echo "There are differences between the $BRANCH1 and $BRANCH2 branches."
else
  echo "There are no differences between the $BRANCH1 and $BRANCH2 branches."
fi
```

Comment: it will fail if we get an error output from this command like branch not found etc.